# javascript, faceapi.js changing text, based on facial expression(happy, sad, angry, etc..)

Tags: javascript, face-api

```
//Displays facial expression
faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
//If facial expression size is greater than 0 (facial expression detected) change the text in p
if (resizedDetections && Object.keys(resizedDetections).length > 0) {
  const expressions = resizedDetections.expressions;
  const emotion = Object.keys(expressions).filter(
    item => expressions[item] === maxValue
  );
    if(`Emotion - ${emotion[0]}` === "happy"){
    //window.location.href="anger.html";
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Red as a ballon,";
    }
}
```

I need help understanding how to get the expression value from face-api and make changes in my html

Answer (score 0):

- go to face-api.min.js
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> search for happy
- you will find all labels change the text and save it

PS: don't use vscode to change the text